# What is the m-th derivative of $f(x)=a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\ldots+a_{2}x^{2}+a_{1}x+a_{0}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

Let there be an arbitrary polynomial of degree $n$: $$f(x)=a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\ldots+a_{2}x^{2}+a_{1}x+a_{0}$$

where the $a_{i}$'s are constants. What would be the m-th derivative of f(x), i.e. $f^{(m)}(x)$?

I figured out there would be 3 cases for $m$ and $n$.

If $m=n$, then $$f^{(m)}(x)=n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdot \ldots \cdot 1\cdot a_{n}\cdot x^{n-m}=n!\cdot a_{n}$$

If $m>n$, then $$f^{(m)}(x)=\frac{d^{m-n} \space f^{(n)}(x)}{dx^{m-n}}=\frac{d^{m-n} \space (n!\cdot a_{n})}{dx^{m-n}}=0$$

But what happens if $m<n$? I couldn't make any sense out of the expression I obtained. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody here wants a complete answer, here's what I found upon a more rigorous approach to the question.

$$f^{(1)}(x)=f'(x)=n\cdot a_{n}\cdot x^{n-1}+(n-1)\cdot a_{n-1}\cdot x^{n-2}+\ldots+2a_{2}x+a_{1}+0$$

$$f^{(2)}(x)=f''(x)=n\cdot (n-1) \cdot a_{n}\cdot x^{n-2}+(n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdot a_{n-1}\cdot x^{n-3}+\ldots+2a_{2}+0+0$$

$$\ldots$$

By observation, for $m<n$:

$$f^{(m)}(x)=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}\cdot a_{n}\cdot x^{n-m}+\frac{(n-1)!}{((n-1)-m)!}\cdot a_{n-1}\cdot x^{(n-1)-m}+\ldots+\frac{m!}{(m-m)!}\cdot a_{m} \cdot x^{m-m}$$

where $m-m=0$.

This can also be written as a sum, starting from the lower value of $m$ up until $n$:

$$f^{(m)}(x)=\sum_{p=m}^{n}\frac{p!}{(p-m)!}\cdot a_{p} \cdot x^{p-m}$$

which is probably the neatest expression of the true response that I wanted to share.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One has, for $p=1,2,\cdots,$ and $m \le p$,
$$
\left(x^p\right)^{(m)}=p\cdot (p-1)\cdot (p-2)\cdots (p-m+1)  \cdot x^{p-m}=\frac{p!}{(p-m)!}\cdot x^{p-m}.
$$

Comment: So would I have something along the lines of: 

$$f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!} \cdot a_{n} \cdot x^{n-m} +\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1-m)!} \cdot a_{n-1} \cdot x^{n-m-1} +\ldots+\frac{(n-(m-1))!}{(n-(m-1)-m)!} \cdot a_{m+1} \cdot x+\frac{(n-m)!}{(n-m-m)!}a_{m}$$

That's what I got initially, but there surely must be a prettier way to write it (I assume).

Comment: @Glycerius Without knowing more concerning the coefficients $a_k$, I doubt one can find a prettier way to write it.

Comment: I understand, well thank you for the suggestion and have a nice day :-)

Comment: @Glycerius You are welcome!